# Bootstrap text alignment is not align

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello I am new to bootstrap and been searching solution for this layout.
I want to achieve something like this:
[image]

But in my code the name,code,status and contact person is not align together.
Here is the snippet:
[image]

Also here is the code:

```
<div class = "col-md-12 border " style ="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
   %{--                    Customer information--}%
   <div class="container-fluid well span6 ">
      <div class="row-fluid ">
         <div class="span8">
            <div class = "row">
               <div class = "col-md-6">
               </div>
               <div class = "col-md-6">
                  <div class = "row">
                     <div class = "col-md-6">
                        <g:if test="${cus.status =='Inactive'}">
                           <g:form class="activateStatus" controller="customer" action="activateStatus" id = "${cus.id}">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success activate-Status" style ="color:white;font-weight: bold">Activate</button>
                           </g:form>
                        </g:if>
                        <g:if test="${cus.status =='Active'}">
                           <g:form class="changeStatus" controller="customer" action="changeStatus" id = "${cus.id}">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger change-Status" style ="color:white;font-weight: bold">Deactivate</button>
                           </g:form>
                        </g:if>
                     </div>
                     <div class = "col-md-3">
                        <g:link action="index" controller="customer"><button id = "back" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style = "font-weight: bold">Back</button></g:link>
                     </div>
                     <div class = "col-md-3">
                        <g:link action="editCustomer" id="${cus.id}"><button id = "edit" type="button" class="btn" style = " font-weight: bold;color: white;background-color:#1f549c"><i id = "add-icon" class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit</button></g:link>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
               <div class = "col-md-12">
                  <h4 style = "text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Name : ${cus.name}</h4>
                  <h4 style = "text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Code: ${cus.code}</h4>
                  <h4 style = "text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Contact Person: ${cus.contactPerson}</h4>
                  <h4 style = "text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Status: ${cus.status}</h4>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it requires some CSS work, you can do it with CSS or you can use bootstrap class for columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last row div should look like that:

```
<div class = "row">
                        <div class = "col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">Name</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 col-sm-1">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">${cus.name}</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">Code</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 col-sm-1">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">${cus.code}</h4>
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">Contact Person</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 col-sm-1">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">${cus.contactPerson}</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">Status</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 col-sm-1">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <h4 class="text-left font-weight-bold">${cus.status}</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

Here is how it looks like now: [image]